# ¿Como puedo subir el volumen de windows desde un .bat?

Tags: .bat

Estoy intentando que desde un .bat se suba el volumen del ordenador sin instalar ningún programa. Por lo que he visto no hay ningún comando que lo permita pero a lo mejor es posible simular la pulsación de la tecla subir volumen que hay en algunos portátiles.

Si alguien conoce alguna manera de hacerlo me sería muy util. Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Revisa esto: https://superuser.com/questions/42039/change-windows-sound-volume-via-the-command-line

Comment: @PatricioMoracho lo he estado mirando y en todas las opciones usa programas como nirCMD que hay que instalar antes de ejecutar el script. No existe ninguna manera de hacerlo todo dentro del mismo .bat?

Comment: Hay una respuesta con PowerShell según ví y otra con javascript, desde un comndo DOS batch seguro no hay nada, tal vez puedas invocar a un script vbs creado previamente desde el BAT

Comment: @julianix ¿para que versión de Windows lo necesitas? ¿Tendrá instalado `powershell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes hacerlo con NirCMD (link de descarga [aqui](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)) en conjunto con el archivo .bat, ahi en la documentacion tenes todos los comandos utiles de windows que podes ejecutar con la herramienta sin desplegar una interfaz. Una vez descargado, descomprimes y en el archivo bat nuevo que crees escribes:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\Unnamed\Desktop\nircmd.exe" // aqui iria la ruta donde colocaste NirCDM.exe
nircmd.exe changesysvolume 10000
```

luego doble click sobre el archivo y listo.

**ALTERNATIVA**

Ahora... otra solución es con Windows Powershell, ábrelo y lo primero es que hay que asegurarse es de tener el módulo *AudioDeviceCmdlets* instalado, para instalarlo abre PowerShell y ejecuta el siguiente comando (si ya lo tienes instalado te notificara).

```
Install-Module -Name AudioDeviceCmdlets -Scope CurrentUser
```

para continuar lo actualizamos en caso de que este desactualizado (si ya lo está te avisara) con el siguiente comando:

```
Update-Module -Name AudioDeviceCmdlets
```

y listo, ya puedes crear tu archivo bat que abrira PowerShell y ejecutara algunos comandos en el:

```
@echo off
powershell Import-Module AudioDeviceCmdlets
powershell Set-AudioDevice -PlaybackVolume 33
```

Este .bat al ejecutarlo cambiara el volumen del dispositivo a 33. En mi caso ha funcionado perfecto. Saludos